# Read JSON using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

I’m working on an application which accesses the TMDb.
I use the DataContractJsonSerializer class to read the data returned by the TMDb API.

There is one method of the API which returns a JSON which can look like:

```
{"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":false,"watchlist":false}
```

or like:

```
{"id":49521,"favorite":false,"rated":{"value":5.5},"watchlist":false}
```

As you can see, the rated field in the first JSON is a Boolean and in the second one it isn’t.
Is there a good way to deal with this JSONs?

Thanks for any Help

**Edit:**
Reading the JSON:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonModelBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T DesterilizeJson(String jsonContent)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonContent);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            return DesterilizeJson(stream);
    }
    public T DesterilizeJson(Stream jsonStream)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class TmdbMovieAccountStates : JsonModelBase<TmdbMovieAccountStates>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "favorite")]
    public Boolean Favorite { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "rated")]
    public Boolean Rated { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "watchlist")]
    public Boolean Watchlist { get; set; }
}
```

Sample (if you want to try something out)

```
var json = "{\"id\":49521,\"favorite\":false,\"rated\":{\"value\":5.5},\"watchlist\":false}";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
using ( var stream = new MemoryStream( bytes ) )
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TmdbMovieAccountStates));
    var data = (TmdbMovieAccountStates)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Comment: You could try using the C# dynamic type.  I won't put this as an answer because I have no idea if it will work.

Comment: Can you show your code where you set the value of rated?

Comment: Added code to question.

Comment: declare `rated` as object, since it can a *booelan* or a complex *object*.

Comment: Using Object as Type works… but how can I access the data in the object when it’s not a Boolean?

Comment: using for ex,`dynamic` keyword.

Comment: If I use the dynamic keyword the value gets stored as Object… which is the same as I use Object as type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with dynamic types I would use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) instead of DataContractJsonSerializer.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TmdbMovieAccountStates>(json);

if (obj.Rated is Boolean)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Rated);
else
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Rated.value);


public class TmdbMovieAccountStates 
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Boolean Favorite { get; set; }
    public dynamic Rated { get; set; }
    public Boolean Watchlist { get; set; }
}
```

You don't even need to declare any class

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);

if (obj.rated is bool)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.rated);
else
    Console.WriteLine(obj.rated.value);
```

Comment: Tanks for the help, I’ll take a look at Json.Net

Answer (score 1):

Try a reader approach instead of a typed object. Newtonsoft uses a dynamic to allow you to read the data and decide what it is and what to do with it as you read it. It's much like e.g. XmlReader. Have a look here http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: Tanks for the help, I’ll take a look at Json.Net