# Turn JSON into a C# List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Sorry, new to Json. Have read up but can't get this working. I have this json formatted string being returned on a .aspx page where I am using C#.

```
{"ContactsListResult":[{"Contact":"Fred Smith","ContactID":25},{"Contact":"Bill Wilson","ContactID":45}]}
```

I have a Contact object.

```
public class Contact
{
public string Contact { get; set; }
public int ContactID { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get each Contact into a Contact object and into a List of Contacts - just using whatever is built into Framework 4.0. I am not interested in the 'ContactsListResult' bit of the Json - I am just interested in the list of contacts within the square brackets.

Comment: are you open to using a nuget package? You could do your own parsing, but there are libraries out there to do what you want, even ones released by microsoft.

Comment: I usually use some nuget package for serializing JSON into C# objects, such as http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json

Comment: At least You could have posted a compilable class.

Comment: What you are interested in is not important. You should parse the complete json to get the part you want.

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {


   class Program {

      [Serializable]
      public class ContactsListResult {
         public string Contact { get; set; }
         public int ContactID { get; set; }
      } //

      [Serializable]
      public class CList {
         public List<ContactsListResult> ContactsListResult = new   List<ContactsListResult>();
      } //

      static void Main(string[] args) {
         string s = "{\"ContactsListResult\":[{\"Contact\":\"Fred Smith\",\"ContactID\":25},{\"Contact\":\"Bill Wilson\",\"ContactID\":45}]}";

         JavaScriptSerializer lSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         CList lItems = lSerializer.Deserialize<CList>(s);

         foreach (ContactsListResult lItem in lItems.ContactsListResult) Console.WriteLine(lItem.Contact + " " + lItem.ContactID);

         Console.ReadLine();
      } //

   } // class
} // namespace
```

Please follow the details on my blog:

http://csharphardcoreprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/json-part-1-basics-follow-up-to-xml/

Bastian M.K. Ohta

Answer (score 0):

`DataContractJsonSerializer` is the class you need to use. See here for a demo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Also, google it. This took me 2 minutes of research.

Here's another stack overflow Q regarding the same item. Someone else recommends JSon.NET
[Read JSON using DataContractJsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263019/read-json-using-datacontractjsonserializer)

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer is the class you need to use` Is it the only built-in class? Why is it better than JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: @L.B You downvoted him because he doesn't know EVERY possible solution there is?  Not fair.  He provided a valid solution.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is another option, but as Rick S said, there are multiple ways of solving any problem. I provided one that I know to work. On the positive side L.B, your comment encouraged me to google for 'alternatives to DataContractJsonSerializer' and I found JavaScriptSerializer. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library where you not have to decorate your clases without any Data Annotation... http://james.newtonking.com/json