# Parseto object from unusual JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "date": "2012-01-05",
    "rate": {
        "GBP": "5.2549",
        "BGN": "2.2189",
        "JPY": "0.043985",
        "AUD": "3.4648",
        "EGP": "0.5601",
        "SEK": "0.4898",
        "BRL": "1.8444",
        "RSD": "0.0412",
        "EUR": "4.3398",
        "CAD": "3.3165",
        "USD": "3.3796",
        "HUF": "0.013449",
        "MXN": "0.2459",
        "MDL": "0.2867",
        "NOK": "0.5646",
        "CZK": "0.1672",
        "KRW": "0.002925",
        "RUB": "0.1057",
        "PLN": "0.9596",
        "CNY": "0.5363",
        "NZD": "2.6406",
        "UAH": "0.4194",
        "XDR": "5.1605",
        "TRY": "1.7911",
        "DKK": "0.5837",
        "INR": "0.0638",
        "CHF": "3.5629",
        "XAU": "175.2918",
        "AED": "0.9201",
        "ZAR": "0.4114"
    }
}
```

I need to get the values from `rate` as a List of Model (`List<Model>` )

```
public class Model
{
    public string Currency {get; set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would refer you to an answer on the thread I created recently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235693/turn-json-into-a-c-sharp-list-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in 2 steps.

### Step - 1:

Deserialize the json string into a class like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> rate { get; set; }
}
```

with the following familiar code:

```
string json = "YOUR_JSON";
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

### Step - 2:

Now you can extract the Dictionary as list of `Model`s using the following LINQ:

```
List<Model> models = root.rate.Select(x => new Model {Currency = x.Key, Value = x.Value}).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't work! I get an error message like: can not convert into 'RootObject'

Comment: if you have the exact json string like above with all the internal `"` preceded by `\\`, then my solution should work, as I have successfully tested it on my side.